# Issue: writing to two different tables in one database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I Have two classes "StaffListDB" and "CostCentreListDB" which are two table structures. I have mentioned DataBase name as "B" for both classes. When I try to write to these tables from an ASYNC task it gives me an error. I tried writing to these tables from two separate ASYNC task still the same issue.
But when I change one of the DataBase name to anything other than "B" to say "DB" it works fine. Any help suggestions much appreciated. Thank you.

```
My database classes:
public class StaffListDB {

    private static final String KEY_STAFFID = "StaffId";
    private static final String KEY_STAFFNAME = "StaffName";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "B";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "StaffList";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBStaffListHelper staffListHelper;
    private final Context staffListContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase staffListDatabase;

    private static class DBStaffListHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBStaffListHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_STAFFID
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_STAFFNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

    public StaffListDB (Context c){
        staffListContext = c;
    }

    public StaffListDB open() throws SQLException{
        staffListHelper = new DBStaffListHelper(staffListContext);
        staffListDatabase = staffListHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;        
    }

    public void close(){
        staffListHelper.close();
    }

    public long createStaffEntry(String staffIdd, String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_STAFFID, staffIdd);
        cv.put(KEY_STAFFNAME, name);        
        return staffListDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);      
    }

    public String getStaffData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_STAFFID, KEY_STAFFNAME};
        Cursor c = staffListDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        String result = "";

        int iStaffId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STAFFID);
        int iStaffName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_STAFFNAME);


        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iStaffId) + " " + c.getString(iStaffName) + "\n";
        }


        return result;
    }

    public void deleteTable() throws SQLException{
        staffListDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    }

}

public class CostCentreListDB {

    private static final String KEY_COSTCODE = "CostCode";
    private static final String KEY_COSTCODENAME = "CCName";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME= "B"; 
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "CostCentreListTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DBCCListHelper ccListHelper;
    private final Context ccListContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ccListDatabase;


    private static class DBCCListHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DBCCListHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_COSTCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                    KEY_COSTCODENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                    );

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);


        }

    }

    public CostCentreListDB (Context c){
        ccListContext = c;
    }

    public CostCentreListDB open() throws SQLException{
        ccListHelper = new DBCCListHelper(ccListContext);
        ccListDatabase = ccListHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;        
    }

    public void close(){
        ccListHelper.close();
    }

    public long createCCEntry(String costCode, String costCodeName) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_COSTCODE, costCode);
        cv.put(KEY_COSTCODENAME, costCodeName);     
        return ccListDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);     
    }

    public String getCCData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_COSTCODE, KEY_COSTCODENAME};
        Cursor c = ccListDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iCostCode = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COSTCODE);
        int iCostCodeName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_COSTCODENAME);


        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iCostCode) + " " + c.getString(iCostCodeName) + "\n";
        }


        return result;
    }


}
```

Async Task :
        public class SaveServerInfoInDataBase extends AsyncTask{

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String staffId = params[0];
            String staffName = params[1];
            for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++){

            StaffListDB saveStaffList = new StaffListDB(MainActivity.this);
            saveStaffList.open();
            //saveStaffList.deleteTable();
            saveStaffList.createStaffEntry(staffId + i, staffName + i);
            saveStaffList.close();          

            CostCentreListDB saveCC = new CostCentreListDB(MainActivity.this);
            saveCC.open();
            saveCC.createCCEntry("200" + i, "IT" + i);
            saveCC.close();

            }
            return null;
        }       

    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
02-09 11:20:42.778: E/SQLiteLog(7104): (1) no such table: CostCentreListTable
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104): Error inserting CostCode=2000 CCName=IT0
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: CostCentreListTable (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO CostCentreListTable(CostCode,CCName) VALUES (?,?)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1108)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:681)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:589)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1573)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1445)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at com.example.testsqlite.CostCentreListDB.createCCEntry(CostCentreListDB.java:69)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at com.example.testsqlite.MainActivity$SaveServerInfoInDataBase.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:90)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at com.example.testsqlite.MainActivity$SaveServerInfoInDataBase.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-09 11:20:43.068: E/SQLiteDatabase(7104):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Why creating 2 nested classed which extends SQLiteOpenHelper ?
Create only 1 class, and handle all your db in it.

Comment: @udi. yes done that now and it is working fine now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two different database connections to write to the same database file is not correct. You will encounter database lock exception when you try to write to the file at the same time using different connections.

You have to ensure that you're using one db connection. you can implement a singleton database helper that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_name";

    private static DataBaseHelper mInstance = null;

    private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public static DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
         if (mInstance == null)
             mInstance = new DataBaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());

        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {/* ... */}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {/* ... */}

}
```

Then use the extended class anywhere

```
public class StaffListDAO {

    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public static String TableName = "StaffList";

    private static final String KEY_STAFFID = "StaffId";
    private static final String KEY_STAFFNAME = "StaffName";

    private StaffListDAO(Context context) {
        mDbHelper = DataBaseHelper.getInstance(context);
    }

    public static StaffListDAO getInstance(Context context) {
        return new StaffListDAO(context);
    }

    public void insert(Staff item) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // fill values

        db.insert(TableName, null, values);
    }

}
```

Notice that I don't usually close the database connection because it will release automatically when the app is finish. You can implement a ref counter to handle db connection close.

Comment: thank you for you valuable suggestions. Yes i made the necessary changes and its working absolutely fine now.